# struct using a pointer, ... in something not a struct or union

Tags: c, struct, assign, dereference, pointer-to-pointer

I defined a structure called coordonnees declared as a pointer, I want to append values to the pointer a_visiter but it's not working. How can I fix that?

Here is the struct code:

```
typedef struct couple
{
    int ligne;
    int colonne;
}*coordonnees;

int main()
{
    coordonnees a_visiter;
    a_visiter=(coordonnees)malloc(DIMENSION*4*sizeof(struct couple));
    int p=0;
etc ...
}
void voisin_egaux(char matrice[][DIMENSION+1],int x, int y,coordonnees **a_visiter,int *p)
{
    if (matrice[x][y]==matrice[x+1][y]){
        (a_visiter+(*p))->ligne=x+1;
        (a_visiter+(*p))->colonne=y;
         ++(*p);
        }
```

I get as an error: request for member ligne in something not a structure or union.

Comment: yes, `(a_visiter+(*p))` is a `coordonnees**`

Comment: Don't use `typedef` for pointer types. As you can see, it becomes confusing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers

Comment: [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Avoid using `(pointer+index)->member`, use `pointer[index].member`

Answer (score 0):

This parameter declaration

```
coordonnees **a_visiter
```

is equivalent to

```
struct couple ***a_visiter
```

Thus the expression

```
(a_visiter+(*p))
```

has the above pointer type that does not point to an object of the structure type.

To make this code semantically valid

```
(a_visiter+(*p))->ligne=x+1;
(a_visiter+(*p))->colonne=y;
```

the parameter should be declared like

```
coordonnees a_visiter
```

Otherwise you need to write

```
( **a_visiter+(*p))->ligne=x+1;
( **a_visiter+(*p))->colonne=y;
```

Comment: I passed the coordoonnees a_visiter by reference because I will use it in another function so I should declare it as coordonnees *a_visiter or coordoonnees a_visiter ?

Comment: @Elas If you want to pass a pointer itself to an object of the structure type by reference then you should declare the parameter like coordonnees *a_visiter. If you want to pass an object of the structure type by reference then you should write coordonnees a_visiter.

Comment: @Elas It really depends on the use-case: Do you need to assign to `a_visiter`, to change where the original pointer is pointing? If not, then just plain `coordoonnees a_visiter`. But I really recommend you read the comment by Barmar: Don't hide pointers behind a type-alias.